# The pagination table with the search option is not working properly

Tags: javascript, html, css

1. Table search is only working on the current page and showing results from the current page. It's not showing the search result from the whole table. I want that search to work for the whole table and show the result from the whole table.
2. The pagination limit is undefined. I want to limit the pagination limit to 2; the next and previous buttons will work accordingly.
3. Showing the current page row count. You can see it at the bottom of the table. It should show the current page row count and then the whole table row count.

```js
 <!-- search starts -->
    function myFunction() {
        var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue, pagination;
        input = document.getElementById("myInput");
        filter = input.value.toLowerCase();
        table = document.getElementById("paginated-list");
        tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
        for (i = 1; i < tr.length; i++) {
            alltags = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td");
            isFound = false;
            for (j = 0; j < alltags.length; j++) {
                td = alltags[j];
                if (td) {
                    txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
                    if (txtValue.toLowerCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                        tr[i].style.display = "";
                        j = alltags.length;
                        isFound = true;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (!isFound && tr[i].className !== "header") {
                tr[i].style.display = "none";
            }
        }
    }
      <!-- search ends -->
    <!-- Row Count starts -->
           var getTableRowCount = function(tableNode) {
            var tbody = tableNode.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
            if (tbody) {
                return tbody.getElementsByTagName('tr').length;
            } else {
                return tableNode.getElementsByTagName('tr').length;
            }

        }
        var count = getTableRowCount(document.getElementById('paginated-list'));
        document.getElementById('rowsNumber').innerHTML = ' of  ' + count;
        document.getElementById('colNumber').innerHTML = 'Showing 1 - ' + count;
    <!-- Row Count ends -->

    <!-- Pagination starts -->
    const paginationNumbers = document.getElementById("pagination-numbers");
    const paginatedList = document.getElementById("paginated-list");
    const listItems = paginatedList.querySelectorAll("tbody tr");
    const nextButton = document.getElementById("next-button");
    const prevButton = document.getElementById("prev-button");

    const paginationLimit = 2;
    const pageCount = Math.ceil(listItems.length / paginationLimit);
    let currentPage = 1;

    const disableButton = (button) => {
        button.classList.add("disabled");
        button.setAttribute("disabled", true);
    };

    const enableButton = (button) => {
        button.classList.remove("disabled");
        button.removeAttribute("disabled");
    };

    const handlePageButtonsStatus = () => {
        if (currentPage === 1) {
            disableButton(prevButton);
        } else {
            enableButton(prevButton);
        }

        if (pageCount === currentPage) {
            disableButton(nextButton);
        } else {
            enableButton(nextButton);
        }
    };

    const handleActivePageNumber = () => {
        document.querySelectorAll(".pagination-number").forEach((button) => {
            button.classList.remove("active");
            const pageIndex = Number(button.getAttribute("page-index"));
            if (pageIndex == currentPage) {
                button.classList.add("active");
            }
        });
    };

    const appendPageNumber = (index) => {
        const pageNumber = document.createElement("button");
        pageNumber.className = "pagination-number";
        pageNumber.innerHTML = index;
        pageNumber.setAttribute("page-index", index);
        pageNumber.setAttribute("aria-label", "Page " + index);

        paginationNumbers.appendChild(pageNumber);
    };

    const getPaginationNumbers = () => {
        for (let i = 1; i <= pageCount; i++) {
            appendPageNumber(i);
        }
    };

    const setCurrentPage = (pageNum) => {
        currentPage = pageNum;

        handleActivePageNumber();
        handlePageButtonsStatus();

        const prevRange = (pageNum - 1) * paginationLimit;
        const currRange = pageNum * paginationLimit;

        listItems.forEach((item, index) => {
            item.classList.add("hidden");
            if (index >= prevRange && index < currRange) {
                item.classList.remove("hidden");
            }
        });
    };

    window.addEventListener("load", () => {
        getPaginationNumbers();
        setCurrentPage(1);

        prevButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
            setCurrentPage(currentPage - 1);
        });

        nextButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
            setCurrentPage(currentPage + 1);
        });

        document.querySelectorAll(".pagination-number").forEach((button) => {
            const pageIndex = Number(button.getAttribute("page-index"));

            if (pageIndex) {
                button.addEventListener("click", () => {
                    setCurrentPage(pageIndex);
                });
            }
        });
    });
     <!-- Pagination ends -->
```

```css
  .result {
            text-align: center;
            padding-bottom: 20px;
            width: 100%;
        }
        
          .canel-trains-grids {
            float: left;
            width: 100%;
            margin-bottom: 20px;
        }
        
        .canel-trains-grids .left-cancel {
            float: left;
            width: 60%;
            margin-top: 10px;
        }
        
        .canel-trains-grids .left-cancel span {
            float: left;
            font-size: 16px;
            background: #34A853;
            color: #fff;
            font-weight: 400;
            padding: 8px 8px;
            border-radius: 3px;
            text-align: left;
            line-height: 1.5em;
            width: auto;
        }
        
        .canel-trains-grids .right-cancel {
            float: right;
            width: 30%;
            margin-top: 10px;
        }
        
        .canel-trains-grids .right-cancel label {
            float: left;
            vertical-align: middle;
            line-height: 39px;
            font-size: 16px;
            color: #000;
            font-weight: 400;
        }
        
        .canel-trains-grids .right-cancel input {
            width: 230px;
            height: 22px;
            border: 1px solid #dae9f3;
            border-radius: 5px;
            padding: 8px 8px 8px 16px;
            float: right;
        }
        
        .canel-trains-grids .right-cancel input:focus {
            outline: none;
        }
        
    
     /* Responsive Table Start */
        
        .rstable {
            width: 100%;
            margin: 0 auto;
            padding: 16px 0px;
        }
        
        .rstable table {
            font-family: calibri, sans-serif;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            font-size: 16px;
            width: 100%;
            font-weight: 400;
        }
        
        .rstable tr {
            border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
        }
        
        .rstable tr td {
            text-align: left;
            padding: 9px;
            color: #333;
        }
        
        .rstable th {
            text-align: left;
            padding: 10px 9px;
            background: #004287;
            color: #fff;
            font-weight: 500;
        }
        
        .rstable tr:nth-child(even) {
            background: #f9fbfdc4;
        }
        
        .rstable tr:nth-child(odd) {
            background: #dae9f3;
        }
        
        .rstable tr td a {
            color: #004287;
            font-size: 16px;
        }
        
        @media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1023px) {
            .rstable table {
                font-size: 15px;
            }
        }
        
        @media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
            .rstable table {
                font-size: 16px;
                font-weight: 400;
            }
            .rstable thead {
                display: none;
            }
            .rstable td:first-child {
                text-align: left;
                display: inline-grid;
                width: 90%;
            }
            .rstable td {
                text-align: left;
                display: inline-grid;
                width: 26%;
                vertical-align: top;
                color: #333;
                font-weight: 400;
            }
            .rstable td:before {
                content: attr(data-title);
                font-weight: 500;
                padding-bottom: 5px;
                font-size: 16px;
                color: #000;
            }
        }
        
        @media (min-width: 280px) and (max-width: 319px) {
            .rstable td {
                width: 23%;
            }
        }
        /* Responsive Table Ends */ 
    
       .arrow-right,
            .arrow-left {
                display: block;
                margin: 10px auto;
                width: 8px;
                height: 8px;
                border-top: 2px solid #000;
                border-left: 2px solid #000;
            }
            
            .arrow-right {
                transform: rotate(135deg);
            }
            
            .arrow-left {
                transform: rotate(-45deg);
            }
            
            .hidden {
                display: none;
            }
            
            .pagination-container {
                width: calc(100% - 0rem);
                display: flex;
                align-items: center;
                position: relative;
                bottom: 0;
                padding: 0rem 0;
                justify-content: right;
                /* text-align: center; */
            }
            
    .pagination-number, .pagination-button {
        font-family: calibri, sans-serif;
        font-size: 16px;
        background-color: transparent;
        border: none;
        margin: 0.1rem 0.1rem;
        cursor: pointer;
        height: 2rem;
        width: 2rem;
        border-radius: 0.2rem;
    }
            
            .pagination-number:hover,
            .pagination-button:not(.disabled):hover {
                background: #fff;
            }
            
            .pagination-number.active {
                color: #fff;
                background: #0085b6;
            }
```

```html
<!-- Result Start -->
        <div class="result">
            <div class='canel-trains-grids'>
                <div class='left-cancel'><span>22 Tech Company Listed</span>
                </div>
                <div class='right-cancel'>
                    <input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder='Enter Train Number'>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <!-- Result Table Starts -->
        
            <div class="rstable">
              <table id="paginated-list">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Extn.</th>
            <th>Joined</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
            <th>Company</th>
            <th>Contact</th>
            <th>Country</th>
            <th>Browser</th>
            <th>Platform</th>
            <th>Engine</th>
            <th>Grade</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td data-title="Name">Airi Satou</td>
            <td data-title="Position">Accountant</td>
            <td data-title="Office">No1</td>
            <td data-title="Extn.">1</td>
            <td data-title="Joined">Mar1</td>
            <td data-title="Salary">GKP</td>
            <td data-title="Company">Island Trading</td>
            <td data-title="Contact">01</td>
            <td data-title="Country">Germany</td>
            <td data-title="Browser">Chrome1</td>
            <td data-title="Platform">Win 10</td>
            <td data-title="Engine">97</td>
            <td data-title="Grade">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td data-title="Name">Angelica Ramos</td>
            <td data-title="Position">CEO</td>
            <td data-title="Office">CR</td>
            <td data-title="Extn.">2</td>
            <td data-title="Joined">Mar2</td>
            <td data-title="Salary">GKP</td>
            <td data-title="Company">Island Trading</td>
            <td data-title="Contact">02</td>
            <td data-title="Country">India</td>
            <td data-title="Browser">Chrome2</td>
            <td data-title="Platform">Win 10</td>
            <td data-title="Engine">96</td>
            <td data-title="Grade">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td data-title="Name">Ashton Cox</td>
            <td data-title="Position">Technical Author</td>
            <td data-title="Office">Software Engineer</td>
            <td data-title="Extn.">3</td>
            <td data-title="Joined">Mar3</td>
            <td data-title="Salary">GKP</td>
            <td data-title="Company">Island Trading</td>
            <td data-title="Contact">03</td>
            <td data-title="Country">Japan</td>
            <td data-title="Browser">Chrome3</td>
            <td data-title="Platform">Win 10</td>
            <td data-title="Engine">95</td>
            <td data-title="Grade">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td data-title="Name">Bradley Greer</td>
            <td data-title="Position">Integration Specialist</td>
            <td data-title="Office">CR</td>
            <td data-title="Extn.">4</td>
            <td data-title="Joined">Mar4</td>
            <td data-title="Salary">GKP</td>
            <td data-title="Company">Island Trading</td>
            <td data-title="Contact">04</td>
            <td data-title="Country">UK</td>
            <td data-title="Browser">Chrome4</td>
            <td data-title="Platform">Win 10</td>
            <td data-title="Engine">94</td>
            <td data-title="Grade">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td data-title="Name">Brenden Wagner</td>
            <td data-title="Position">Software Engineer</td>
            <td data-title="Office">CR</td>
            <td data-title="Extn.">5</td>
            <td data-title="Joined">Mar</td>
            <td data-title="Salary">GKP</td>
            <td data-title="Company">Island Trading</td>
            <td data-title="Contact">05</td>
            <td data-title="Country">USA</td>
            <td data-title="Browser">Chrome5</td>
            <td data-title="Platform">Win 10</td>
            <td data-title="Engine">93</td>
            <td data-title="Grade">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td data-title="Name">Brielle Williamson</td>
            <td data-title="Position">Pre-Sales Support</td>
            <td data-title="Office">CR</td>
            <td data-title="Extn.">6</td>
            <td data-title="Joined">Mar</td>
            <td data-title="Salary">GKP</td>
            <td data-title="Company">Island Trading</td>
            <td data-title="Contact">06</td>
            <td data-title="Country">Canada</td>
            <td data-title="Browser">Chrome6</td>
            <td data-title="Platform">Win 10</td>
            <td data-title="Engine">92</td>
            <td data-title="Grade">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td data-title="Name">Bruno Nash</td>
            <td data-title="Position">Sales Assistant</td>
            <td data-title="Office">CR</td>
            <td data-title="Extn.">7</td>
            <td data-title="Joined">Mar</td>
            <td data-title="Salary">GKP</td>
            <td data-title="Company">Island Trading</td>
            <td data-title="Contact">07</td>
            <td data-title="Country">Italy</td>
            <td data-title="Browser">Chrome7</td>
            <td data-title="Platform">Win 10</td>
            <td data-title="Engine">91 </td>
            <td data-title="Grade">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td data-title="Name">Caesar Vance</td>
            <td data-title="Position">Javascript Developer</td>
            <td data-title="Office">CR</td>
            <td data-title="Extn.">8</td>
            <td data-title="Joined">Mar</td>
            <td data-title="Salary">GKP</td>
            <td data-title="Company">Island Trading</td>
            <td data-title="Contact">08</td>
            <td data-title="Country">Mexico</td>
            <td data-title="Browser">Chrome8</td>
            <td data-title="Platform">Win 10</td>
            <td data-title="Engine">90</td>
            <td data-title="Grade">A</td>
        </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>

        </div>
        
        <div style="width: 100%; display: flex;align-items: center;">
            <div style="text-align: left; width: 50%;">
                <span id="colNumber"></span><span id="rowsNumber"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="pagination-container">
                <button class="pagination-button" id="prev-button" aria-label="Previous page" title="Previous page">
                <span class="arrow-left"></span>
        </button>
                <div id="pagination-numbers">
                </div>
                <button class="pagination-button" id="next-button" aria-label="Next page" title="Next page">
                <span class="arrow-right"></span>
            </button>

            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Result Table Ends -->
```

Comment: Is there a JavaScript expert who can help me with this?

Comment: @ezw, expecting response from you.